# Custom package installation path in Composer?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Is it possible to specify that our own packages in Composer are installed to a different folder than `vendor/`. I know that I can specify a folder where *all* packages are installed, but that's not what I want. I want third party packages to end up in `vendor/` and our own within `src/` folder.

Is this possible? We are using Symfony 2 if that matters.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably make own installer: http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md and use own `installer-paths`

Comment: Show me more example please. I want to require with version specified.

Answer (score 4):

I have implemented this composer plugin to install packages into user (custom) defined folders you can just include it in your composer.json, follow the example and tell me if you have more questions :)

https://github.com/mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer

## composer-custom-directory-installer

A composer plugin, to install differenty types of composer packages in custom directories outside the default composer default installation path which is in the `vendor` folder.

This is not another `composer-installer` library for supporting non-composer package types i.e. `application` .. etc. This is only to add the flexability of installing composer packages outside the vendor folder. This package only supports `composer` package types,

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type

> The type of the package. It defaults to library.
>
> Package types are used for custom installation logic. If you have a package that needs some special logic, you can define a custom type. This could be a symfony-bundle, a wordpress-plugin or a typo3-module. These types will all be specific to certain projects, and they will need to provide an installer capable of installing packages of that type.

### How to use

- Include the composer plugin into your `composer.json` `require` section::

```json
"require":{
    "php": ">=5.3",
    "mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer": "1.1.*",
    "monolog/monolog": "*"
  }
```

- In the `extra` section define the custom directory you want to the package to be installed in::

```json
  "extra":{
    "installer-paths":{
      "./monolog/": ["monolog/monolog"]
    }
```

by adding the `installer-paths` part, you are telling composer to install the `monolog` package inside the `monolog` folder in your root directory.

- As an added new feature, we have added more flexibility in defining your download directory same like the `composer/installers`, in other words you can use variables like `{$vendor}` and `{$name}` in your `installer-path` section:

```json
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "./customlibs/{$vendor}/db/{$name}": ["doctrine/orm"]
    }
}
```

the above will manage to install the `doctrine/orm` package in the root folder of your project, under `customlibs`.

### Note

Composer `type: project` is not supported in this installer, as packages with type `project` only make sense to be used with application shells like `symfony/framework-standard-edition`, to be required by another package.

Comment: SO prefers at least some basic information on what the link contains. Then if the link goes stale your post still has value.

Comment: Sorry, I implemented a composer plugin to install composer packages in custom directories provided in composer.json file :)

Answer (score 0):

If still a case consider testing my library (based on a plugin by [mina.nsami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3277020/mina-nsami) ):

https://github.com/ideaconnect/composer-custom-directory

Allows custom paths:

```
"extra":{
    "installer-paths":{
      "./monolog/": ["monolog/monolog"]
}
```

and even dynamic name replacements:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "./packages/{$name}": ["sourcepackage/package_A","sourcepackage/package_B","sourcepackage/package_B"]
    }
},
```

and with flags chain which allows a simple manipulation of the variables on runtime:

Currently supported flags are:

```
F - capitalizes first letter.
P - changes all entries of a _ or - followed by a character to only that character, capitalized.
```